Node deditcated only for specyfic pods
I have a cluster with a node where I only want to run specific pods. I want to make in the way, that pods without any additional configs will not be scheduled on this node. Can and how can I achieve it?

I love how such nice community can degrade... Any tips how to improve this question? Or just downvote or close just because? Preferably anonymously of course.

Please see the [help/on-topic] for more details about what's acceptable on Stack Overflow; configuring detailed Kubernetes Pod placement doesn't really seem like it's specifically related to programming.  There's also a dedicated Kubernetes documentation page on Assigning Pods to Nods.  In most cases, particularly with appropriate resource requests, the cluster scheduler does just fine at keeping workloads out of each others' way and you shouldn't usually need any sort of manual placement.

thx @DavidMaze "it's specifically related to programming" it is a valid point. I checked the tag and similar config questions are here so I dropped it here. Apparently one of other stack child will be more suitable here. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392643

To restrict a node to run only specific pods, you can use taints and tolerations. Start by tainting your node to prevent all pods from scheduling on it unless they have a specific toleration. You can run a command like this command to apply the taint:
kubectl taint nodes <node-name> dedicated=special-workloads:NoSchedule

Then, in the pod spec for the pods you want to allow on this node, add a matching toleration like this:
tolerations:
  - key: "dedicated"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "special-workloads"
    effect: "NoSchedule"

This will ensure that only pods with this toleration will be scheduled on the node, while others will automatically be kept off.
You can learn more here, in the official K8s docs.
